# Getting the lengthiest path in an array, functional style

Tags: javascript, svg, functional-programming, geometry

I have an array of SVG lines that represent the sides of a triangle, I want to color the lengthiest one (the hypotenuse). Assuming `ab`, `bc` and `ca` are the the SVG `line` elements...

```
var hypotenuse = [ab, bc, ca].sort(getLineLength)[0];
hypotenuse.setAttribute("stroke-width", 5);

function getLineLength(el) {
    var x1 = el.getAttribute("x1");
    var x2 = el.getAttribute("x2");
    var y1 = el.getAttribute("y1");
    var y2 = el.getAttribute("y2");
    var xs = x2 - x1;
    var ys = y2 - y1;
    xs = xs * xs;
    ys = ys * ys;
    return Math.sqrt(xs + ys);
}​
```

This doesn't work, it seems it grabs the first element always. It also doesn't look very intuitive. What is the correct way to achieve this in Javascript? I know how to do it in loops but I'd like to know if there's some functional idiom that allows me to achieve this.

JSFiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/btbkd/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `function` in `array.sort(function)` expects two arguments, and you should return an Integer which is

- less than zero (indicates that the first one should be prior than the second one);
- zero (indicates that the two is equal);
- larger than zero (indicates that the second  one is prior than the first one).

[MDN Document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Also you forgot to reset the line width.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/btbkd/2/)

**Edit**:

Noted that I get rid of the `Math.sqrt` part from your `getLineLength` function, because if comparing is all that you expect from this function, calculating square root is not necessary, and removing it may make it a little bit faster.

Comment: @Duopixel Glad to be of help :)

Answer (score 2):

When you pass a function to sort(), that function has to take two arguments and return the result of comparing them (-1, 0, or 1), or if comparing numbers then you can just subtract the two arguments: [Mozilla Array.sort Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

A simple way to make your example work should be something like this:

```
var hypotenuse = [ab, bc, ca].sort(function(lineOne, lineTwo) {
    return getLineLength(lineTwo) - getLineLength(lineOne);
})[0];
```

And then the rest like you already have. Note that the order of the subtraction is important, as it will be the difference between sorting from lowest to highest or from highest to lowest.

Comment: Note that you may wish to cache the results of `getLineLength` if you expect to be calling this a lot since it will be called more than once per line.

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember JavaScript syntax, so the syntax may be wrong, but if I understand your question correctly no sort() should be necessary and you should be able to do:

```
var maxLength = 0;
var longestElement = -1;
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if( getLineLength(array[i]) > maxLength )
        longestElement = i;
}
```

If longestElement is -1, there is no line with a length greater than 0. Otherwise, hypotenuse is array[longestElement].

Note that neither this nor the sort() example does any special handling for lines of equal length (e.g. an equilateral triangle).